# Solr Customization using Java for modified output?

Tags: java, php, solr, lucene

I am developing an application uaing Solr. Everything is going fine and I am looking ahead to integrate Solr with CodeIgniter or some other framework for frontend. But there is a problem. I am performing some calculations on output rows thrown by Solr and showing them to users. It is really not feasible to do in PHP ( as it takes really long time). I have an existing code written in Java and hence, I find no reason in porting this application to PHP. How can I do that? Is there anyway I can insert my Java code on a certain query to modify output? Please note, operations I am performing are on Solr results only, so getting results is a must and then operations on them. Please suggest me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you are developing a Front-end in PHP but want to reuse Java code to handle solr results to be presented on your front-end... Probably you have two ways to go:

1. Crete simple Java "web service" that processes your Solr results and give them to your PHP  front-end (so the PHP application needs to call the Java web service, that has the code you refer to)... for that you could use something like: Jersey (https://jersey.java.net/) to create a java web service.
2. (probably the best one, if you are writing your Web applicaiton in PHP) you should look in more detail on Solr PHP clients (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP).

Comment: If I go for first option, I have to read Solr output from command line, perform operations on it and output a JSon for PHP to read for front end ?

Comment: You need to call the Java web service, and indeed you can put the web service sending a JSON for PHP... I think you could even simply have in you PHP code a call to the Java web service (deployed on a Tomcat/JBoss/etc.), which could read the data you have from Solr (you can get the data from Solr directly using a java solr client - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj - so you would not need to do things in the command line... but I do not know your application)... and provide the data in JSON to the PHP application...

Comment: That sounds feasible for doing. But is there anyway I can tweak solr itself, and add my code there. I mean customization of solr outputs. I think it would require ultimate breakdown of solr code, a month long process.

Comment: On tweaking Solr code I cannot help... but not sure if you will have big advantages to one of the solutions proposed.

Comment: I want to use it for analytics purpose and not for search application. Will try your way first. Thanks.

Comment: if you can read this, I have to give input to solrj as well. I mean in Java, I have to perform operations on input by user which I am taking from user. Can you please suggest something for this /

Comment: It is not clear what you mean... solrj is a Java client for Solr, so it allows you to query directly Solr from your java code (e.g.: use user "input text" to make your search in Solr)... If you have this in your Java web service, you can retrieve the Solr documents directly from your java code... and then apply the "operations" you say in you have implemented in Java... Not sure this is what you mean.

Comment: ok I got it. Thanks a lot. I have to output json from java for reading in php.