# Embedding Java libraries (Solr) in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, solr, playframework, playframework-2.0

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781609/solr-customization-using-java-for-modified-output) and got the answer. I have another related query before proceeding. I am processing possibilities of using Play Framework (any Java framework for that matter) for frontend to reduce the load of calling a java application running Solrj and making output in Json and reading on frontend via PHP to display. I am wondered if I use Play Framework and as we know, Solrj can work inherently with Java, I can have a class for Solrj in my application and can work on it directly without need of reading any JSON. Does it sounds a good idea? Or will it greatly slowdown site load time due to loading of Solrj everytime. It can be considered a general question as well, not just for Solj.

> Is it feasible to use different Java libraries with Play Framework, or
>   should I do all processing in a different application, provide output
>   to Play Framework as Json , read it from there. Does it make any
>   difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven repository even generates Scala/SBT code for including it into project/Build.scala. Its kinda easy to add Solrj into your project.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.3.1

You can call Solr from Play using its HTTP and JSON libraries:

[Call Solr asynchronous from Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270393/call-solr-asynchronous-from-play-framework/17315047#17315047)